# присвоение переменной значения из свойства объекта

Tags: python

изучая питон, наткнулся на некоторые особенности языка.
Допустим, есть объект со свойством. я присваиваю двум переменным значение этого свойства, а затем начинаю изменять одну из переменных. после чего получаю одинаковый результат в обеих переменных.

```
object.text = "hello"
var1 = object.text
var2 = object.text
var2 = var2+" world"
# теперь и var1 = hello world
```

работаю с telethon, создавать отдельную копию события нельзя, а в интернете костыли по типу copy() и создания разноразмерных костылей.

Природу этого явления я понимаю, а вот как решить - не знаю.

Comment: дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: В чем проблема с copy()? Объекты просто при присваивании не копируются. Если нужна копия, то нужно коприровать.

Comment: В целом, приведенный код описанных проблем не должен вызывать, изменится значение только в var2 (если только сложение для объекта из поля text не переопределено как мутирующая операция, что вообще лучше не делать). Добавьте конкретный код, с которым у вас возникла проблема.

Comment: Пример явно оторван от жизни. Строки обычно копируются при сложении, проблем тут не должно быть, переменные будут указывать на разные строки. А вот если у вас ссылка например на список и вы делаете `.append`, тогда другое дело. И да, `.copy` - это не костыль, это совершенно нормально, когда вам нужна копия объекта, а не две ссылки на один и тот же объект.

Answer (score -1):

aleksandr barakin указал где можно найти решения.
мне помог способ со срезом. его плюс в том, что не нужно импортировать лишние библиотеки.

```
b = a[:]
```

против

```
import copy
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
```

Comment: Вообще-то чтобы написать `a.copy()` тоже не нужно ничего импортировать. Это тоже самое, что `a[:]`, только в другом виде. Оба варианта делают "поверхностную копию", если же вам нужна "глубокая копия", то срез вам её не сделает, её сделает только `copy.deepcopy`.